# Critera for geometry or geography

Tags: sql-server, geometry, geography

What criteria do you need to take account to before you choose geometry or geography map?

Is there a book or page about it?

Comment: in which software?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: I am using Geography

Comment: Check out following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx I hope it will help you..